# I am developing an app and would like cordova functionality when using the browser as well in this case spesifically chrome

Tags: firebase, cordova

Want to be able to deploy my app to Firebase and use Cordova functionality in the browser. Get an error that cordova_not_available when opening the firebase website.

To be able to run Cordova on the browser in this case chrome in the first place I added the browser platform to my project and the use the Cordova run command instead of serve.

But when I deploy to the website I get the Cordova not available error

Comment: Cordova functionality is only available in Cordova, not in a standalone browser. See https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/pwa-how-to-access-cordova-plugins-in-pwa-web-applications/147575 That said, the functionality you need may be available in some other way. But in order to help with that, you'll have to be a bit more concrete about what you're trying to accomplish by using this Cordova functionality.

Comment: There are a lot of plugins being used in the app. But to simplify what I'm trying to accomplish. I have files stored on the firestore, and then on android and iOS, I used the file and the file transfer plugin to download the file and save it locally.

When using Cordova run I can do this on the browser as well. Then when I deploy the app to the firebase website I don't have Cordova functionality anymore. Is there a way to create a Cordova run instead of serve for the firebase deploy.

Comment: Nope. Firebase Hosting hosts web sites, not Cordova apps. The latter are run as native apps on your device, providing extra native functionality to your JavaScript code. A lot of that functionality is these days also available directly in browser APIs, but it may have a different form there. You'll have to look at each piece of functionality in turn, and possibly reimplement it using native APIs for the web platform.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but suspected this might be the case, probably continue looking for a fancier solution. But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `cordova-browser` platform to run in any modern browser. [More info](https://github.com/apache/cordova-browser)

Now, when you run for a browser, you need to keep in mind to

1. include `cordova.js` in your `index.html`
2. include plugins which also support a browser platform. (most plugins support ios and android, so heads up on this)

> [Device plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device) is one such plugin which supports a browser platform.
>   Have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyjmmDWqmzk) on how you can configure and run device
>   plugin with Cordova on chrome.

Specific to your case, more chances that you get the error *cordova not available* is because you might have missed adding `cordova.js` to your `index.html` file.

Comment: will this also work when serving the app to website format like when serving to firebase website

Comment: @JeffreySkinner Firebase supports websites, so ideally you would not have any issues. Again, its JavaScript, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova functionality is only available in Cordova, not in a standalone browser. See https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/pwa-how-to-access-cordova-plugins-in-pwa-web-applications/147575

Firebase Hosting hosts web sites, not Cordova apps. The latter are run as native apps on your device, providing extra native functionality to your JavaScript code. A lot of that functionality is these days also available directly in browser APIs, but it may have a different form there. You'll have to look at each piece of functionality in turn, and possibly reimplement it using native APIs for the web platform.

Comment: you are ruling out the fact that `cordova-browser` exits. Cordova can run in any modern browser, the only issue is that plugins you use alongside should also support a browser platform

Comment: Hey Nidhin. Thanks for chiming in. My answer was based on a quick search and the result I linked. Great to hear that there may be alternatives.

Comment: Yep, mostly Cordova is known to be related to mobile apps than applications in the browser which makes to the point that it only supports mobile apps.